# Does igraph has a function that generates sub-graphs limited by weights? dfs, random_walk

Tags: r, igraph, weighted, subgraph

I have a weighted graph in igraph R environment.

And need to obtain sub-graphs recursively, starting from any random node. The sum of weights in each sub-graph has to be less them a number.

The Deep First Search algorithm seems to deal with this problem. Also the random walk function.

Does anybody know which igraph function could tackle this?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're after. Could you provide example code, and specify if you're in R or Python? What is the recursive side of your problem? I guessed that you would like to write a function that takes a numeric threshold-value `n` and a graph `g` and returns a subgraph of at least one specified random node `x`, and that the subgraph should include all connected (directly or indirectly) nodes to `x` over as many iterations as the sum of the edge-weights to all surrounding connected nodes remains below `n`? Am I guessing correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to do! I will post an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This iterative function finds the sub-graph grown from vertex `vertex` of any undirected `graph` which contains the biggest possible weight-sum below a value spevified in `limit`.

A challange in finding such a graph is the computational load of evaluating the weight sum of any possible sub-graphs. Consider this example, where one iteration has found a sub-graph A-B with a weight sum of 1.

[image]

The shortest path to any new vertex is A-C (with a weight of 3), a sub-graph of A-B-D has a weight-sum of 6, while A-B-C would have a weight-sum of 12 because of the inclusion of the edge B-C in the sub-graph.

The function below looks ahead and evaluates iterative steps by choosing to gradually enlarge the sub-graph by including the next vertex that would result in the lowest sub-graph weight-sum rather than that vertex which has the shortest direct paths.

In terms of optimisation, this leaves something to be desired, but I think id does what you requested in your first question.

```
find_maxweight_subgraph_from <- function(graph, vertex, limit=0, sub_graph=c(vertex), current_ws=0){
  # Keep a shortlist of possible edges to go next
  shortlist = data.frame(k=integer(0),ws=numeric(0))
  limit <- min(limit, sum(E(graph)$weight))

  while(current_ws < limit){
    # To find the next possible vertexes to include, a listing of 
    # potential candidates is computed to be able to choose the most
    # efficient one.
    # Each iteration chooses amongst vertecies that are connected to the sub-graph:
    adjacents <- as.vector(adjacent_vertices(graph, vertex, mode="all")[[1]])

    # A shortlist of possible enlargements of the sub-graph is kept to be able
    # to compare each potential enlargement of the sub-graph and always choose
    # the one which results in the smallest increase of sub-graph weight-sum.
    #
    # The shortlist is enlarged by vertecies that are:
    #  1) adjacent to the latest added vertex
    #  2) not alread IN the sub-graph
    new_k <- adjacents[!adjacents %in% sub_graph]
    shortlist <- rbind(shortlist[!is.na(shortlist$k),],
                       data.frame(k = new_k,
                                  ws = rep(Inf, length(new_k)) )
    )

    # The addition to the weight-sum is NOT calculated by the weight on individual
    # edges leading to vertecies on the shortlist BUT on the ACTUAL weight-sum of
    # a sub-graph that would be the result of adding a vertex `k` to the sub-graph.
    shortlist$ws <- sapply(shortlist$k, function(x) sum( E(induced_subgraph(graph, c(sub_graph,x)))$weight ) )

    # We choose the vertex with the lowest impact on weight-sum:
    shortlist <- shortlist[order(shortlist$ws),]

    vertex <- shortlist$k[1]
    current_ws <- shortlist$ws[1]
    shortlist <- shortlist[2:nrow(shortlist),]

    # Each iteration adds a new vertex to the sub-graph
    if(current_ws <= limit){
      sub_graph <- c(sub_graph, vertex)
    }
  }

  (induced_subgraph(graph, sub_graph))
}

# Test function using a random graph
g <- erdos.renyi.game(16, 30, type="gnm", directed=F)
E(g)$weight <- sample(1:1000/100, length(E(g)))
sum(E(g)$weight)
plot(g, edge.width = E(g)$weight, vertex.size=2)

sg <- find_maxweight_subgraph_from(g, vertex=12, limit=60)
sum(E(sg)$weight)
plot(sg, edge.width = E(sg)$weight, vertex.size=2)

# Test function using your example code:
g <- make_tree(10, children = 2, mode = c("undirected"))
s <- seq(1:10)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value= s)
plot(g, edge.width = E(g)$weight)

sg <- find_maxweight_subgraph_from(g, 2, 47)
sum(E(sg)$weight)
plot(sg, edge.width = E(g)$weight)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I will test it tomorrow and tell you if it is better and faster than my DFS. I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

It is done here below, however, it does not seem to be effective.

```
#######Example code
g <- make_tree(10, children = 2, mode = c("undirected"))
s <- seq(1:19)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value= s)
plot(g)
is_weighted(g)
E(g)$weight


threshold <- 5 
eval <- function(r){
  #r <- 10
  Vertice_dfs <- dfs(g, root = r)
  Sequencia <- as.numeric(Vertice_dfs$order)
  for (i in 1:length(Sequencia)) {
   #i <- 2
   # function callback by vertice to dfs
   f.in <- function(graph, data, extra) {
    data[1] == Sequencia[i]-1
   }
   # DFS algorithm to the function
   dfs <- dfs(g, root = r,in.callback=f.in) 
   # Vertices resulted from DFS 
   dfs_eges <- na.omit(as.numeric(dfs$order))
   # Rsulted subgraph
   g2 <- induced_subgraph(g, dfs_eges)
   # Total weight subgraph g2
   T_W <- sum(E(g2)$weight)
     if (T_W > threshold) {
      print(T_W) 
      return(T_W)
      break
     }
  }
}

#search by vertice
result <- lapply(1:length(V(g)),eval)
```

Comment: You aught to add the code as an edit to your question instead of providing a non-functioning answer.

Comment: Oh.. This is actually an interesting problem, and quite an optimisation challenge :)

Comment: This is a functional answer. However, I assume this is a non-effective because of the time-consuming.